# Communicate between two TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

At work, I have two instances of `teamcity` servers.

The first one is mine, on which i run my builds, however due to issues related to `SMTP Client` I am unable to send emails on build success and failures. And due to bureaucracy unfortunately that won't be done. (Development/Prod Support Categorization)

and the other `teamcity` instance where the email is already setup (as this is in Production Category).

I wanted to leverage this but i don't want to re setup everything on that teamcity rather just use that as a reporting medium.

How can i proceed with the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a build configuration on the production category TeamCity instance that can send the notifications and invoke it from the development TeamCity instance over [REST API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html).

Comment: Thanks Anton, however can I get all the build status over rest api in my production tc like overview, changes. My main objective here is to identify the developer who introduced a bug and send him an email.. So I atleast need the changes to be reported back to prod team city